# eval() not working with ggplot, returns "non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following ggplot element stored as **text**:

```
eval(parse(text = " annotate('text', as.Date('2013-12-31'), 30.31049879  * 1.02,
       label = paste0( 19.48 , percent( 0.055 )), color = 'Blue') +
       annotate('text', as.Date('2013-12-31'), 33.341548669  * 1.02,
       label = paste0( 21.43 , percent( 0.048 )), color = 'Blue') "))
```

eval() returns error "non-numeric argument to binary operator" since it's trying to add the two parts together, but the plus sign is used differently with ggplot. Is there any way to dodge this problem?

Comment: What are you using the `parse` function for?   Since you are hard coding everything, would it not be easier to just have the `annotate()` simply.

Comment: @Jrakru56 I have about twenty of those annotations so I figured out it might be easier to add them using a loop instead of hardcoding twenty rows.

Comment: if that's the case, then you might be better off creating a `data.frame` or `list` to hold your `x`, `y` and '`label`

Comment: Soemthing like this: `dt<- mtcars;
ggplot(data=dt) + geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y =hp )) + geom_text(aes(label = rownames(dt), x =mpg, y = hp))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by putting `ggplot() +` at the start of the code, i.e.

```
eval(parse(text = "ggplot() +
annotate('text', as.Date('2013-12-31'), 30.31049879  * 1.02,
           label = paste0( 19.48 , percent( 0.055 )), color = 'Blue') +
               annotate('text', as.Date('2013-12-31'), 33.341548669  * 1.02,
               label = paste0( 21.43 , percent( 0.048 )), color = 'Blue') "))
```